# invalid conversion from 'long int' to 'void (*)()' [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, pointers, bootloader

Hi I am writing little modified code for the bootloader for MCU's. The modification I am trying to do is power the boot loader even for an watchdog timer reset.

I am using this function prototype to define the address of the boot loader and I get the error :

> invalid conversion from 'long int' to 'void (*)()' [-fpermissive]

My code is

```
#if defined ( __AVR_ATmega1284P__ )
    void (*boot_start)(void) = 0xF000;
#elif defined ( __AVR_ATmega2560__ ) 
    void (*boot_start)(void) = 0x1F000;
#endif
```

Where the 0xF000 and 0x1F000 are memory spaces. I don't get this error if my code is `

```
void (*boot_start)(void) = 0x0000;
```

Why ??

Comment: If you're compiling this with another compiler than what it was written for, you're sure to get more problems than just this one...

Comment: @hvd: this has nothing to do with compilers.  It is about CPU architecture and memory mapping.

Comment: @stefaanv It's both. The code is not written to be valid in any particular standard (nor can it be) and relies on compiler extensions. As you can see in this question it relies on an implicit conversion from integral types to pointer types, but no such implicit conversion exists in standard C++. This newer version of the compiler (or perhaps even a different compiler entirely, but I think it's probably a newer version) does not support the same extensions, at least not by default. There are almost certainly other extensions that the code is relying upon that break similarly.

Comment: @hvd: the implicit conversion is just plain wrong and doesn't compile, which is why the question was asked.  My comment was on filling function addresses with integral values, which is possible via casting, but can only work if the CPU architecture allows it.

Comment: @hvd: i commented on your "get more problems".  I don't see any more problems than not being able to compile from a compiler point of vue.

Comment: @stefaanv It's not "just plain wrong". It's non-standard, but it's written for a compiler that allows it. As for getting more problems, I don't expect those five lines to be the only lines in the project, and I expect the many other lines to also use extensions that would also require updating to work with the OP's current compiler. If they're not updated, they may cause different compiler errors, or they may even cause the code to fail badly at run-time, due to different optimisations. Much simpler to just use the compiler it was written for, in my opinion, at least for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compiler recognize `0xF000` as `int` and discard assigning this value to pointer. You should cast it explicitly:

```
void (*boot_start)(void) = (void (*)())0xF000;
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. It worked it out for me. The issue is that the compiler warns as stating that 0xF000 is not a pointer though it is. Your solution clearly works. I have made it much more simple from suggestion from avrfreaks of using typedef, <code> typedef void (*fptr_t)(void);

fptr_t boot_start = (fptr_t)0xF000; </code>

Answer (score 3):

0x0000 is just another name for NULL and will compile ok as a pointer value, but the other values need to be explicitly cast to the correct type.

Comment: Isn't NULL defined as `(void*)0`? Because void pointers are implicitly convertible to any other pointer type?

Comment: @Vorac are you sure you got language tag right? Your comment is valid in C, but completely wrong in C++. First: NULL should be a literal 0 of integral type. It cannot be a pointer type. Second: void pointers cannot be converted to anything implicitely. You can convert to them, but not from them.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot, thanks for the reality check, I was indeed thinking in C. I don't plan on reading the 1500+ pages C++ standard any time soon.

Answer (score 0):

The answer that I got from AVRFreak forum,

USE TYPEDEF,

```
typedef void (*fptr_t)(void);

fptr_t boot_start = (fptr_t)0xF000;

...
  boot_start();
```

The reason you get the warning otherwise is that 0xF000 is a long int for an AVR. The thing on the left of '=' was a pointer to a function. So you are trying to assign an integer to a pointer. C thinks this is probably a mistake (often it is!) so it warns you. The way you quell that warning is to say "no this 0xF000 number really is a pointer value". The way you do that is with a typecast. Now you could do this with (wait for it):

```
void (*boot_start)(void) = (void(*)(void))0xF000;
```

But as you can see in that there is almost exactly the same (quite complex) structure on both side of the equals. So it makes sense to put all that detail into one single typedef and use it in multiple places.

If the function type were more complex this might even be something like:

```
int (*boot_start)(char, long, int *) = (int (*)(char, long, int *))0xF000;
```

and this starts to look very silly indeed - not only is it very likely you make a typing error it's just trying to remember the syntax here is a real pain! So you use typedef to define the function interface just once:

```
typedef int (*myfn_t)(char, long, int *);

myfn_t boot_start  = (myfn_t))0xF000;
```

and that gets to be easier to type and easier to manage. If you later add a fourth char ** parameter to the function you now do it in just one place - the typedef.

Thanks to C Lawson and Yuriy.